# How to process different case of Same Word in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

```
<xs:simpleType name="PowerUnit">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
        <xs:enumeration value="MWh"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="mWh"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Jaxb is Unable to generate class for the above example where spelling of  MWh and mWh is same but different case. Even, JAXB doesn't show any  error. Simply it  generate other file except this enumeration.

How to handle this scenario?

Comment: Could you show your `jaxb` code?

Comment: I am using command line xjc.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XML Schema (schema.xsd)**

Below is a sample XML schema based on your question.  I had to change the base type to `string` to make it valid.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org" 
    xmlns="http://www.example.org"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:simpleType name="PowerUnit">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="MWh" />
            <xs:enumeration value="mWh" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="power-unit" type="PowerUnit"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

**Default Generated Class**

If the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation is not able to generate an enum then it will create a property of the base type.

```
package org.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "root", propOrder = {
    "powerUnit"
})
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "power-unit", required = true)
    protected String powerUnit;

    public String getPowerUnit() {
        return powerUnit;
    }

}
```

**External Binding File (binding.xml)**

You can use an external binding file to rename one of the items in the enumeration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='PowerUnit']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='mWh']">
            <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="M"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

**New Generated Class**

Now that the name conflict in the enumeration has been resolved an enum will be used in the generated JAXB model.

```
package org.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "root", propOrder = {
    "powerUnit"
})
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "power-unit", required = true)
    protected PowerUnit powerUnit;

}
```

**Enum (PowerUnit)**

Below is what the generated `enum` would look like:

```
package org.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlType(name = "PowerUnit")
@XmlEnum
public enum PowerUnit {

    @XmlEnumValue("MWh")
    M_WH("MWh"),
    @XmlEnumValue("mWh")
    MWH2("mWh");
    private final String value;

    PowerUnit(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static PowerUnit fromValue(String v) {
        for (PowerUnit c: PowerUnit.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```